# Identify subject in sentences using spacy in advanced cases

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm trying to identify the subject in a sentence.  I tried to use some of the [code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39334628/1938988):

```
import spacy
nlp = nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
sent = "the python can be used to find objects."
#sent = "The bears in the forest, which has tall trees, are very scary"
doc=nlp(sent)

sentence = next(doc.sents) 

for word in sentence:
    print(word,word.dep_)
```

This returns the results:

- the det
- python nsubjpass
- can aux
- be auxpass
- used ROOT
- to aux
- find xcomp
- objects dobj

I would think in this case the python would be the subject, in most cases that would be the `_dep` would be `nsubj`, but its `nsubjpass`.  So if `nsubj` is not present I can check for `nsubjpass` but are there any other `_dep` it could be?

Is there a more robust way to determine subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence is a passive voice example. `nsubjpass` is the subject when using passive voice

You can find the list of `dep_` by calling

```
for label in nlp.get_pipe("parser").labels:
    print(label, " -- ", spacy.explain(label))
```

I can see there are 2 more subject types:

```
csubj  --  clausal subject
csubjpass  --  clausal subject (passive)
```

One possible way to determine the subject:

```
if "subj" in word.dep_:
    # continue
```

Comment: Could you give a small explanation of what it means to use a passive voice, and are those the only 2 types of nsubj there are?

Comment: I edited my answer to provide some more details. The question about passive voice is purely grammatical. I recommend to google about active and passive voice

Comment: Thanks for the help, I accepted the answer I'll do a bit of independent research